# Would a misconfiguration in cookies and/or postfields lead to this 500 internal server error when using wp_remote_post to post data within Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, curl

I am connecting to a server that does not have a published API and have successfully been able to use the PHP curl functions to retrieve a token and login, but when I try to use Wordpress built-in functions to achieve the same thing, I am not successful and receive a 500 Internal Server Error from the remote host. I believe that I may need to properly configure the cookies and/or data parameters.

I am able to retrieve a token from the remote host using wp_remote_get. I have tried changing the Content-Type to text, json and other common alternatives, although 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' worked fine when using curl. I have tried sending the token in the header as well as in post fields.

```
// I am trying to get this to work:

$token = get_transient('access_token');
if (!$token)
    return;

$args = array(
    'method'      => 'POST',
    'timeout'     => 45,
    'redirection' => 5,
    'httpversion' => '1.0',
    'blocking'    => true,
    'compress'    => true,
    'headers'     => array(
        'Authority' => 'remote.site.com',
        'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Referer' => 'remote.site.com/login',
        'Cache-Control' => 'max-age=0',
        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests' => 1,
        'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36',
        'Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'Accept-Language' => 'zh-CN,zh;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,ms;q=0.7,zh-TW;q=0.6,fr;q=0.5',
        'Accept' => 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3'
    ),
    'cookies'     => array(),
    'body'        => array(
        '__RequestVerificationToken' => $token,
        'UserName' => USERNAME,
        'Password' => PASSWORD,
        'RememberMe' => true
    )
);

$response = wp_remote_post( 'remote.site.com', $args);
```

// and no issue doing it this way...

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'remote.site.com/login');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "__RequestVerificationToken=$token&UserName=JohnDoe&Password=password&RememberMe=true");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip, deflate');

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Authority: remote.site.com';
$headers[] = 'Cache-Control: max-age=0';
$headers[] = 'Origin: https://remote.site.com';
$headers[] = 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1';
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
$headers[] = 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36';
$headers[] = 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8';
$headers[] = 'Referer: https://remote.site.com/login';
$headers[] = 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br';
$headers[] = 'Accept-Language: zh-CN,zh;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,ms;q=0.7,zh-TW;q=0.6,fr;q=0.5';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,  $cookiefile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookiefile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
```

When using curl functions, I get 302 response for the login request and subsequent requests are fulfilled, whereas with wp_remote_post I get a response with the login page and a 500 internal server error response.

Answer (score 0):

```
add code inside the wp-config file
```

define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] );

```
define( 'ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/' );
```

define( 'COOKIEPATH', '/' );

define( 'SITECOOKIEPATH', '/' );

Comment: Yeah that didn't make a difference unfortunately.